# Cant parse RAW DATA with JQ

Tags: json, bash, jq

I want to create a JSON from the list of servers that are stored inside a variable but I get a parse error.

How can I make this work? I think quoting each server might work but I can't do that since the data is retrieved from a CSV using curl.

```
server_list=$(curl http://localhost/api/server_list.csv | cut -d ',' -f2);
echo $server_list
host001 host002 host003 host004

echo $server_list | jq '.'
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 15
```

if that had worked then I could run the following command to create json.

```
echo $server_list | jq -r '.' | jq -s '{hosts:map({"hostid":.})}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One invocation of jq is sufficient:

```
jq -R 'split(" ") | {hosts:map({"hostid":.})}' <<< "$server_list"
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
echo $server_list | jq -R 'split (" ")'  | jq '.[]' | jq -s '{hosts:map({"hostid":.})}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `echo $server_list | jq -R '.' | jq -s '{hosts:map({"hostid":.})}'` will produce:

```
{
  "hosts": [
    {
      "hostid": "host001 host002 host003 host004"
    }
  ]
}
```

Not sure if that is exactly what you are expecting for output, but hopefully helps.

With a little bit of additional manipulation within `jq` you can easily expand the output result.

```
echo $server_list | jq -s -R '{hosts:split(" ")|map(split("\n"))|map({"hostid": .[0]})}'
{
  "hosts": [
    {
      "hostid": "host001"
    },
    {
      "hostid": "host002"
    },
    {
      "hostid": "host003"
    },
    {
      "hostid": "host004"
    }
  ]
}
```